# Is there any native way to implement AJAX form submission without a button?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I need to implement a form that automatically saves data on each element change. So I can add a button with ajax callback and trigger mousedown on this button on "change" event using jQuery. 
And naturally I should hide this button. So this works ok, but it seems to be some ugly solution.

Is there any native Drupal way to make ajax form submission on each element change without a hidden button?

Comment: Actually, it's a native behavior in Drupal 8 as per the documentation https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/ajax-forms if you need more help, please share your code so we can have a look

Comment: No there isn't. Submit handlers are only called when a submit button is clicked, it's how the Form API works. I use the exact method you've described for dealing with such situations, where I want an ajax event to trigger the form submit handler, but without a submit button.